# Using percents within integers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've asked myself a long time how I can use percentages within an integer. Actually like declaring the height and width in CSS...

[ EXAMPLE ]

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
                    var scrollVal = $(window).scrollTop();

                    if(scrollVal >= 472.141) {
                        $("nav").css("position", "fixed");
                        $("nav").css("padding-top", "0");
                        $("nav ul").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(rgba(230, 230, 230, 1) 5%, rgba(230, 230, 230, 0))");
                    } else {
                        $("nav").css("position", "relative");
                        $("nav").css("padding-top", "35%");
                        $("nav ul").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(rgba(250, 250, 250, 0), rgba(250, 250, 250, 1) 95%)");
                    }
                });
```

Here I'd like the percentages in as integer --> `if(scrollVal >= 472.141)` --> `472.141` should be `35%` --> `if(scrollVal >= 35%)`

It would be cool, because the `scrollVal` can be relative to the size of the screen...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 35% of *what*?  How would JavaScript know what that refers to?

Comment: `(scrollVal / $('body').height()) > 0.35 `?

Comment: I don't know exactly, because I'm still learing to code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create your own function to convert percentage value to corresponding number of pixels :

```js
  const heightPercent = percent => window.innerHeight * percent / 100;

  console.log(heightPercent(50));
  console.log(heightPercent(10));
  console.log(heightPercent(100));
```

Then `if(scrollVal >= 472.141)` become `if(scrollVal >= heightPercent(35))`.

Answer (score 0):

one way around this would be to add css classes depending on your position. For example:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollVal = $(window).scrollTop();

        if(scrollVal >= 472.141) {
            $("nav").addClass('class0');
            $("nav").removeClass('class1');
        } else {
            $("nav").addClass('class1');
            $("nav").removeClass('class0');
        }
});
```